# Он объяснил, что покинет страну на фоне "резонанса, который создают события в моей частной жизни". Правильно ли так писать?

Tags: прямая-речь

Он объяснил, что покинет страну на фоне "резонанса, который создают события в моей частной жизни".

Можно ли так писать? Если бы не было кавычек, то следовало бы написать так:

Он объяснил, что покинет страну на фоне резонанса, который создают события в его частной жизни.

Но есть необходимость подчеркнуть, что слова передаются дословно.

Или можно так:

Он объяснил, что покинет страну на фоне "резонанса, который создают события" в его "частной жизни".

Answer (score 2):

Как при чтении, так и в восприятии на слух этого сообщения возможны недоразумения: легко отнести "события частной жизни" к *говорящему*, а не к тому, на кого он ссылается. Только дочитав вопрос, я понял, что говорится о "частной жизни" *другого* лица. Поэтому предложение лучше перестроить, добавив слова, проясняющие границы цитируемого, прежде всего начало цитаты; местоимение же, во избежание неясностей, придется вынести за её пределы и отнести к третьему лицу, например:

> Он объяснил, что покинет страну на фоне, *говоря его словами*,
> “резонанса, который создают события" его частной жизни.

Не совсем понятно, что означает "на фоне": если это указание на причину, то так и нужно выразиться (по причине и т. п.); иной возможный смысл - что это сопутствующее явление, придающее отъезду дополнительную окраску. Выбор - по смыслу.

Comment: Тоже обратил внимание на этот "фон". Он или должен быть включён в цитату (если был там), или вся эта конструкция намекает на приём выдёргивания слов из контекста. Тогда уж лучше обойтись только косвенной речью.

Comment: @Alex_ander  Прочитав, ваш ответ, я поняла, что вас В ОСНОВНОМ беспокоит неясность смысла, и эта проблема действительно здесь присутствует. Но вот такой вопрос: вы могли бы так построить предложение (хотя бы без точного цитирования этого автора), чтобы  оно включало цитату, взятую в кавычки, но при этом местоимения были бы разные, то есть "он" и "я". ВОЗМОЖНО  ЛИ  такое В ПРИНЦИПЕ при  цитировании? Мне показалось, что вы это допускаете.

Comment: А фон, мне он не представляется особо важным словом. Это просто оборот речи, оно здесь вместо служебного. Можно сказать: Он объяснил, что покинет страну в связи с резонансом..."

Comment: Я не вижу такой возможности: в устной речи никакой интонацией эту полную цитату не пристроить (независимо от выбора местоимения). А если нельзя это произнести с ясным смыслом, то и на письме пунктуация не спасет (т. е. не существует ни "правильного" места кавычек, ни даже присоединительной конструкции для _полной_ записи ее в косвенной речи). "На фоне" же плохо тем, что неоднозначность выражения (то ли виноват этот фон в отъезде, то ли пикантности ему придает) создаёт впечатление неуверенности говорящего в связывании слов, он будто "подбрасывает" их адресату, чтобы тот понимал их как хочет.

Answer (score 1):

Я написала бы так:

*Он объяснил, что покинет страну на фоне **"резонанса"**, вызванного событиями в его частной жизни.*

Пояснение

1. Предложенный вариант записи неверен, так как нужна обязательная **замена местоимения.** Разные местоимения возможны только **в прямой речи**, для всех остальных видов  это запрещено.
2. В прямом высказывании  есть **стилистическая погрешность**, так как сложно сразу на слух определить В.п. местоимения "который".
3. Поэтому лучше оставить кавычки только для слова "резонанс".

Comment: Извините, Sharon, а разве есть необходимость брать слово "резонанс" в кавычки? У Ожегова: резонанс — 3. перен. Отзвук, отголосок, впечатление, произведённое на многих. http://endic.ru/ozhegov/Rezonans-30098.html

Comment: Это я так дословное высказывание пытаюсь выделить, но не очень удачно получилось, так как кавычки по-разному можно понять. В действительности  дословность здесь вряд ли можно нормально оформить.

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли так писать?

Тут вопрос надо прежде всего ставить "А нужно ли?". Это не прямая в чистом виде речь, так что замена "моей" на "его" вполне возможна.

**Он объяснил, что покинет страну на фоне "резонанса, который создают события в его частной жизни".**
Так что смысла писать именно так нет никакого.

Теперь насчет "можно ли". Не уверен, хотя, полагаю, с точки зрения грамматики запрета такого нет. Но двусмысленность действительно возникает весьма нежелательная. В английском, если не ошибаюсь, такое оформление повествования подпадает под категорию "косвенно-прямой речи" - и проблем с ней нету, но то в английском.

Остаются две возможности. Либо использовать несобственно-прямую речь, но тут нужно добавить какой-то глагол повествования, здесь это потребует значительной перестройки фразы, не могу даже рекомендовать какой-либо вариант. Либо, что много проще, добавить источник повествования.

***Он объяснил, что покинет страну на фоне "резонанса, который создают события в моей (Хуана-Карлоса - ред.) частной жизни"***.

Или

***Он объяснил, что покинет страну на фоне, как он выразился, "резонанса, который создают события в моей частной жизни"***.

(+)

Предложения расширить или, наоборот, сузить текст, забираемый в кавычки, мне не нравятся. Это нарушает понимание того, что именно сказал беглый экс-монарх, а что является интерпретацией комментаторов. Тут, правда, еще и проблема перевода, а с испанским у меня совсем плохо. Но думаю, что письменный-то текст перевели правильно. Кто не в курсе: эта фраза целиком из письма Хуана-Карлоса своему сыну, нынешнему Королю Филиппу.